# Not moving through array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been making a game, my problem is when you click the space key it shoots 1 bullet, but when you do it again nothing happens. I have made it so the game starts with 30 bullets, and they are stored at the top left of screen out of view. When space is clicked they get fired from the tip of your ship using its X, Y values.

Click here to see what I mean:
http://www.taffatech.com/DarkOrbit.html
- as you can see only 1 fires, ever.

Here is the bullet object

```
function Bullet() //space weapon uses this
{
this.srcX = 0;
this.srcY = 1240;
this.drawX = -20;
this.drawY = 0;
this.width = 11;
this.height = 4;
this.bulletSpeed = 3;
this.bulletReset = -20;
}

Bullet.prototype.draw = function()
{

this.drawX += this.bulletSpeed;
ctxPlayer.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.width,this.height,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.width,this.height);

if (this.drawX > canvasWidth)
  {
  this.drawX = this.bulletReset;

  }

}

Bullet.prototype.fire = function(startX, startY)
{

   this.drawX = startX;
   this.drawY = startY;

}
```

This is the player Object: (the ship)

```
function Player()  //Object
{

//////Your ships values
this.PlayerHullMax = 1000;
this.PlayerHull = 1000;
this.PlayerShieldMax = 1000;
this.PlayerShield = 347;
this.SpaceCrystal = 2684;
this.Speed = 5; //should be around 2 pixels every-time draw is called by interval, directly linked to the fps global variable
////////////

///////////flags
this.isUpKey = false;  
this.isDownKey = false;
this.isLeftKey = false;
this.isRightKey = false;
////////space Weapon
this.noseX = this.drawX + 100;
this.noseY = this.drawY + 30;

this.isSpaceBar =  false;
this.isShooting = false;
this.bullets = [];
this.currentBullet = 0;
this.bulletAmount = 30;

for(var i = 0; i < this.bulletAmount; i++) //
   {

     this.bullets[this.bullets.length] = new Bullet();

   }
/////////////

////Pick Ship
this.type = "Cruiser";
this.srcX = PlayerSrcXPicker(this.type);
this.srcY = PlayerSrcYPicker(this.type);
this.drawX = PlayerdrawXPicker(this.type);
this.drawY = PlayerdrawYPicker(this.type);
this.playerWidth = PlayerWidthPicker(this.type);
this.playerHeight = PlayerHeightPicker(this.type);
////


}

Player.prototype.draw = function()
{
ClearPlayerCanvas();
ctxPlayer.globalAlpha=1;
this.checkDirection(); //must before draw pic to canvas because you have new coords now from the click

this.noseX = this.drawX + (this.playerWidth-10);
this.noseY = this.drawY + (this.playerHeight/2);
this.checkShooting();
this.drawAllBullets();



ctxPlayer.drawImage(spriteImage,this.srcX,this.srcY,this.playerWidth,this.playerHeight,this.drawX,this.drawY,this.playerWidth,this.playerHeight);

};


Player.prototype.drawAllBullets = function()
{

  for(var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++)
   {
     if(this.bullets[i].drawX >= 0)
     {

       this.bullets[i].draw();

     }

   }
}


Player.prototype.checkShooting = function()
{

   if(this.isSpaceBar == true && this.isShooting == false)
   {

        this.isShooting = true;
        this.bullets[this.currentBullet].fire(this.noseX, this.noseY);
        this.currentBullet++;

      if(this.currentBullet >= this.bullets.length)
      {
        this.currentBullet = 0;
      }


      else if(this.isSpaceBar == false)
      {

        this.isShooting = false;
      }

     }
}
```

This is in a method that checks what keys are down:

```
if (KeyID === 32 )  //spacebar
{

Player1.isSpaceBar = true;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

}
```

This is in a method that checks what keys are up:

```
if (KeyID === 32 )  //left and a keyboard buttons
{

Player1.isSpaceBar = false;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

}
```

Any other info you need just ask!

Comment: Maybe you should try to debug a little bit to narrow down where the problem lies. Try logging the flow of your program and the state of variables using `console.log`. We can help you more easily if we don't have to debug your entire program.

Comment: you can press F12 in chrome to open the developer tools. Firefox has a built in version as well but I usually install Firebug, that opens with F12 as well

Comment: I added some alerts and they seem to be working, but other than that Im lost as to what might be the cause :/

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < this.bulletAmount; i++)  {     this.bullets[this.bullets.length] = new Bullet();}
Like this line should make 30 bullets so I don't see the issue being there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out

try adding isShooting  false to the key up event

```
if (KeyID === 32 )  //left and a keyboard buttons
{

Player1.isSpaceBar = false;
Player1.isShooting = false;
e.preventDefault(); //webpage dont scroll when playing

}
```

Comment: Well done sir, thanks! I was just replying to your last message when it said it has been edited :) Correct answer! ;)